# Image not displaying at runtime C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, visual-studio

I am trying to display an image in WPF but for some reason, the image won't show! It appears on the Visual Studio editor but when I run the application it doesn't appear.

Here is some of my code:

This is how I'm trying to display the image:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="273,147,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="image.jpg"/>
```

I have also tried using this:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/image.jpg"
```

Comment: Have you tried searching SO? A quick search which may be of help reveals : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880946/how-to-load-image-to-wpf-in-runtime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636047/image-in-wpf-button-not-visible-at-runtime

Comment: The trick is to add the image file to your Visual Studio project and set its Build Action to Resource (which it should be by default).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In your project:

1. Create a folder say "img", right click on it and select add existing item add image to folder
2. Go to properties of the added image, set `Build Action` as `Resource`.

It worked for me.

In XAML

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="MyImg" Height="80" Margin="273,147,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/img/Desert.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I had to set the Build Action to `Embedded Resource`

Comment: I had to do several builds and rebuilds also cleaned up the `bin` and `obj` folder and finally checked the option "Copy always" for "Output Directory" to make it work eventually. And I can say the Image `Name`, `Width`, `Height`, etc. are not playing a role for displaying the image. What is essential here is to make the VS finally build the correct version with the image embedded in the executable.

Comment: For that Path you do not need to set to Resource, Content is enough. If you set it to Resource and 'Copy to output directory' true it will be compiled into the assembly and additionally copied to the output directory - so effectively shipped twice.

Comment: I also had to Build -> Clean Solution, Build Solution to make it work.

Comment: Seems that someone at M$ still hasn't gotten the 'memo' - you MUST CLEAN and then RE-BUILD for the changes to take effect. Seems curiously odd, but this is what works.

Answer (score 16):

If none of these work, try changing the **Build Action** to **Content**.

That's what worked for me after struggling for a long time with this.

Comment: Thanks. Tried `Resource` and `Embedded Resource` as suggested here and `Content` is the one that worked for me with .NET 6.

Comment: Content also works in VS 2022 with .NET 6.

Comment: @MikeUpjohn Same for me. VS2022, tried most options and Content is the way to go. Maybe one time I will actually read up on what they mean :-))

Answer (score 12):

Go to the properties for the image in Visual Studio and change "Build Action" to "Resource" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".

I had to do a rebuild, but then it worked. Cred to swapnil.

Answer (score 2):

please drag the image to a image source,it will be like this **/img/image.jpg"/**

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="273,147,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/img/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: i did this bt it didn't work. syntax is correct but you nedd to change image properties.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above works, try Rebuilding your application from the build menu. Not "Build", but "Rebuild"

Answer (score 1):

For example, this is your project structure

```
+ProjectName
+--+imagesFolder
|  +--amogus.png
|
+--App.xaml
+--MainWindow.xaml
+--etc.
```

and you want to access the to amogus.png in your xaml window,
You have two ways:

> note this way the imagesFolder will be visible in the release build to users

1. to set amogus.png `Build Action` to `Content` and
   `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022#set-a-build-action),
   then `rebuild` from the build menu, then add this to the window xaml

```
    <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,/imagesFolder/amogus.png" ></Image>
```

> note this way the imagesFolder will be not visible in the release build to users

2. to set amogus.png `Build Action` to `Resource` and
   `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy` or `blank` [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022#set-a-build-action),
   then `rebuild` from the build menu, then add this to the window xaml

```
    <Image Source="/imagesFolder/amogus.png" ></Image>
```

[more detail](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2005/12/more-on-resource-loading-in-wpf.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click your project name in solution explorer and select `Add -> New Folder`.
2. Name this folder as `Images`
3. Right click to Images folder and select `Add -> Existing item` and then select your `image.png` file
4. On your image.png properties adjust `build action -> Resource`
5. Now your image source is `Source="Images/image.jpg"`
6. You should see your image on design window of VS. `Do not forget to clean code before` compiling

Answer (score 0):

Right click images on the Solution Explorer, choose Properties and then set the Build Action as **Resource**.

Answer (score 0):

Did not have to do a clean and rebuild. I tried every combination listed above (I am in VS2017)

1. Go to Project->Properties->Resources
2. Select File (drop down with choices of strings, images, icons...)
3. Click Add Resource->Existing File
4. Navigate to the image and import it
5. VS identifies it as an image (mine is PNG) and switches the view to show Image resources
6. Select the thumbnail of the image and in the Properties of the Image (type should be Bitmap) set **Persistence** to **Embedded in resx**
7. I saved and closed Project Properties as I got confused here before
8. Go to the Resources folder under the project and select the image (it should be listed for you)
9. Select the image and set the **BuildAction** to **Embedded Resource**
10. I set the File Action to  *Copy if Newer*

From here I move back and forth between Debug and runtime, various combinations of clean, build and publish and the image has **FINALLY** been displayed every time.

Last tidbit, the XAML in the dialog looks like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/DeathSpiral.png" />
```

I have updated several projects that were supposed to display graphics but didn't always do so using the steps above.  They all work now.  Tested in both VS2017 and VS2019 and no errors so far.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using relative pathing in XAML:

```
<Image Source="../../Assets/QuickSettingsScreenImage.png"/>
```

And in the csproj file creating an `ItemGroup`, and setting the images as `Resource`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Assets\QuickSettingsScreenImage.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After making the changes, I had to use the **Rebuild Project** button to get the image showing up correctly.

As a note, I am on dotnet 6

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image into the project and set its Properties\Build Action to Resource (Do not copy). Use this for the xaml part.

```
<Image Source="/<asm_name>;component/<image prj_path>"/>

<!-- this also works -->
<Image Source="/<image prj_path>"/>
```

If using the former, refer to the project's Properties\Application tab to get the assembly's exact name.

Answer (score 0):

for those who didn't get it to work after trying all these answers, I found this in my .csproj file and just remove it, it works!!

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\img1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was trying to include a `.svg` file, which apparently [isn't supported by default](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_image.htm). By only changing from a `svg` file to `jpg` file with everything else staying the same, my image suddenly appeared.