# WPF image in button does not appear at runtime but yes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

I am trying to add an image to a button. This is the xaml snippet of the button:

```
<Button Grid.Column="3">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="/images/MonkeyFlow-Logo-Green-Trans-96x96.png"/>
        <TextBlock> test</TextBlock>                        
    </StackPanel>                    
</Button>
```

And this is how it looks in Visual Studio:

[image]

However, when executing the application the window looks like this, like if the image wasn´t loaded and therefore the text "test" takes over the whole button area:

[image]

The image is stored in a project folder called "images" and I tried setting its property 'Build Action' to 'Content', 'Resource' and 'Embeded Resource' with no luck, cleaning, rebuilding and building the solution several times.
I have also read and tried these posts with not luck:

[Image not displaying at runtime C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049511/image-not-displaying-at-runtime-c-sharp-wpf)

[WPF Button with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697383/wpf-button-with-image)

Many thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated

Comment: Set the build action to content and the copy to output directory to always or copy if newer.

Comment: Thank you @KostasK. I just tried but I am afraid that it does not not work :(

Comment: Build Action should be Resource. Besides that, we cannot tell what you might have done wrong. The code in your question looks ok.